# Removing the Allow Null check box ,, require the table to be re-created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Sql server 2008 R2, and i use to have a table with a column that can have null values. but now i want to alter the column type to not allow null values. so what i did is that i simply , go to the

> table--> click on design -->

on the column i removed the allow null check box. but i receive a warning message from the sql server 2008 r2 , that the table will be re-created for the chnage to apply . so can anyone advice what is causing this issue?

Comment: Just use a TSQL ALTER TABLE statement for this. Don't bother with the designer.

Comment: how i can write such a statment ?

Comment: Name of table? Name of column? Datatype?

Comment: i run this command "ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn INT NOT NULL ".but still the check box is checked beside the column,, not sure why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn INT NOT NULL
```

Change the table name, column name and datatype in the above example as required.

There is no need to rebuild the entire table.

This is a size of data operation though [and can cause significant logged activity in some circumstances](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29522/3690).

Comment: well i run this command , and i received "Command(s) completed successfully.".but still the check box is checked beside the column,, not sure why this is happening ?

Comment: Close the window down and reopen it.